# How to avoid downtime migrating from AWS to GCP? Typically for load balancing and SSL setup

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, openssl, migration, load-balancing

I'm trying to migrate a bitnami wordpress from AWS to GCP. I would like to avoid downtime during migration. As a new learner, I am not sure how to best handle this.

I have encountered some roadblocks. Typically on **Load Balancer** and **SSL**

1. I would like to use a load balancer on GCP. I prefer Google's managed certificate but the domain's IP is tied to AWS's server. I have to release them from AWS first and that will be quite a bit of downtime waiting for GCP to validate and provision.
2. If I were to use own certificate on GCP's load balancer just for the migration purpose to avoid downtime, will there be downtime if I switch back to Google's managed SSL?
3. The bitnami wordpress VM's on GCP has a dummy self-signed root certificate pointing to **example.com** [CN=example.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TgyY.png) that I can't remove, more likely I don't know how to. How can I remove or replace that with actual domain name?
4. I am unable to generate a LetsEncrypt on GCP's server because the domain is still tied to AWS's server. Again, I have to release them first before I can use it on GCP and that will result in downtime.
5. If I use SSL on loadbalancer, do I still need to install SSL on server? Will the virtual host 443 work without SSL installed on the server?
6. Is it possible to create the loadbalancer without providing a SSL for frontend? I don't see an option to do so on GCP's console.

I understand my questions are probably very elementary. I really appreciate any directions at this point.

Thanks

Comment: Hi there! About 1. You can add more than one IP to an A record and customers will redirect to AWS and GCP, once migration its over, you only remove the other IP from the A record. What you are looking its named: "DNS-Based Load Balancing"

Comment: About the managed certificate. Unless you use a MIG or K8s, you can not usre L7 Load Balancers in GCP. Is that your case?

Comment: About 4), you can use DNS validation with lets encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge

Comment: About 5), only if you want extra security. Normally users only use TLS certs from Internet to the LB, but from LB to the VM you can use http. Is not the best practice to use http, but may save you some extra effort and time

Comment: About 6, yes, you can use L7 LB for HTTP : https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#types-of-cloud-load-balancing

Comment: And about 2, yes.

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas really really appreciate it! Yes, I'm using MIG.

Comment: Hi @ArmandoCuevas Do you want to provide this as an answer so that I can accept it?